# sh module: how to use piping with sudo?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i use the [`sh` module](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/) ([github.com/amoffat/sh](https://github.com/amoffat/sh)) quite often. now i have come across a problem i do not know how to solve: how can i pipe the output of one command into a second command; both commands need to be run with root privileges (yes, i could start a shell as `root` first and then run the commands [how would i to that using `sh`?]).

this is all for the current version: `1.12.14`.

the [recipe to run commands as `root`](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/sudo.html?highlight=sudo#using-sudo) is:

```
from getpass import getpass, getuser
import sh

password = getpass('[sudo] password for {}: '.format(getuser()))

with sh.contrib.sudo(password=password, _with=True):
    ls = sh.ls()
    print(ls)
```

the [recipe for piping is](https://amoffat.github.io/sh/sections/piping.html#advanced):

```
import sh

for line in sh.tr(sh.cat("test.log", _piped=True),
                  "[:upper:]", "[:lower:]", _iter=True):
    print(line)
```

both work just fine.

but combining them does not (as pointed out by [tripleee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) this is a silly example; in the real use-case both commands really do need `sudo` privileges):

```
from getpass import getpass, getuser
import sh

password = getpass('[sudo] password for {}: '.format(getuser()))

with sh.contrib.sudo(password=password, _with=True):
    for line in sh.tr(sh.cat("test.log", _piped=True),
                      "[:upper:]", "[:lower:]", _iter=True):
        print(line)
```

this crashes with the error:

```
Exception in thread background thread for pid 5163:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/workdir/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/workdir/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/workdir/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/workdir/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/sudo -S /usr/bin/tr [:upper:] [:lower:]

  STDOUT:

  STDERR:
[sudo] password for user: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sh_test.py", line 42, in <module>
    sudo_redirect()
  File "sh_test.py", line 38, in sudo_redirect
    "[:upper:]", "[:lower:]", _iter=True):
  File "/workdir/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/workdir/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/workdir/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/sudo -S /usr/bin/tr [:upper:] [:lower:]

  STDOUT:

  STDERR:
[sudo] password for user: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for user: sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

it looks as if `sh` passes the password to `sudo` using the `-S | --stdin` flag (read password from `stdin`). and this seems to conflict the piping...

so my **question** is: is there a way to have both? `sudo` and piping?

---

for the time being i use this **workaround** (i am sure there are better ways!). the bash command i try to imitate is this:

```
sudo -k; echo 'password' | sudo -S -v 2>/dev/null;
sudo cat test.log | sudo tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]
```

the `sudo -k` is only here to clear the cached user's credentials and make sure any of this really works... and it will only work if sudo is configured to cache the credentials (for a minimal amount of time).

using the [`subprocess` modlue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) i use:

```
from getpass import getpass, getuser
import subrpocess

password = getpass('[sudo] password for {}: '.format(getuser()))

echo_passwd = subprocess.Popen(('echo', password),
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
subprocess.check_output(('sudo', '-S', '-v'),
                        stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                        stdin=echo_passwd.stdout)
echo_passwd.wait()

cat = subprocess.Popen(
    ('sudo', 'cat', 'test.log'),
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out = subprocess.check_output(('sudo', 'tr', "[:upper:]", "[:lower:]"),
                        stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                        stdin=cat.stdout)
cat.wait()

print(out)
```

Comment: You want to give `sudo` to the command which requires access to a privileged resource, but generally never to any others, for obvious security reasons.  Specifically, `sudo tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]` is just a very risky, unnecessary, and silly thing to do because `tr` doesn't require any privileges to perform this operation. (But of course, it's a poor example, because Python can replace uppercase with lowercase trivially in native code.)

Comment: @tripleee i agree; but that is just because i simplified the example and wanted to stay as close to the doc as possible (with code that works and can be tested by anyone) instead of the real code. my use-case is something like `sudo btrfs send -p parent_snapshot dst_snapshot | sudo btrfs receive target_directory`. where both parts need sudo privileges. ...i might have to clear that up in the question.

Comment: @tripleee i fear you might want to award a [Useless Use of `cat` Award](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) for that... (in the original code in the `sh`-doc it's `tail -f` instead of `cat`, but again: simpler to test...)

Comment: [Indeed I may](/a/47746942/874188) (-: but `sudo cat` is actually a sane way to pipe a privileged file to an unprivileged pipeline.